# Using a function with ternary operand as the new value parameter in Javascript replace function

Tags: javascript

I'm chaining together a handful of .replace calls, and want to be able to offer default replacement values via an inline function.  Here's some example code

```
bar = {};
foo = "test";
foo = foo.replace("test", function(){typeof bar.baz !== 'undefined'? bar.baz : "default_text"});
```

In this example, `foo` is set to `"undefined"` instead of `"default_text"`

if I provide a similar function that simply returns:

```
bar = {}
foo = "test"
foo = foo.replace("test", function(){ return "something" });
```

`foo` is set to `"something"`.  What about the ternary operand, OR my code in general is preventing the expected behavior in this case?  Are there any possible alternative solutions that would allow me to set default text, inline (I understand I can wrap the replaces in an `if..then`, checking that the object property exists, but for the use case it would not be optimal)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple mistake, you forgot the return

```
foo = foo.replace("test", function(){ return typeof bar.baz !== 'undefined'? bar.baz : "default_text"});
                                      ^^^^^^
```